# Delphi ORed together vs + difference

Tags: delphi

Not too long ago, I used `TFileStream.Create(Source,fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyNone)`,
and I was told that I should use `or` instead of `+`.

I've googled, but perhaps I searched the wrong way. I also looked at the source code for `.Create`.

And then I have decided that I should simply try to see what the difference is.

```
var
  Mode : Word;
  Mode2 : Word;

begin

  Mode := 1 or 16;  // $0001 or $0010
  Mode2 := 1 + 16;  // $0001 + $0010

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Mode)+' '+IntToStr(Mode2));

end;
```

I was expecting a difference, but I may be doing this wrong.

****What is the difference between `or` vs `+`, for example in `TFileStream.Create`** ?**

---

**UPDATE**

I just realized that I really did this the wrong way.

```
Mode := 1 or 1;
```

vs

```
Mode := 1 + 1;
```

Makes a difference, first is 1, second is 2.

It would still be great if someone could point me to some documentation on how/why exactly it works like this.

`Mode := 2 or 6` vs `Mode2 := 6 or 6`, first one is 6, second one is 6.

Comment: Yes, you must use `or` and not `+`. When you combine to bitfields, you use `or` to get the "union". For instance, maybe `00101` means NOT DOG, NOT CAT, RAT, NOT HORSE, BIRD. That's your competence as a veterinarian. Your college has `10100` which means DOG, NOT CAT, RAT, NOT HORSE, NOT BIRD. Your combined competence is then `00101 or 10100 = 10101` which means DOG, NOT CAT, RAT, NOT HORSE, BIRD. That's correct. But if you compute `00101 + 10100 = 11001` which means DOG, CAT, NOT RAT, NOT HORSE, BIRD which is wrong.

Comment: Here's the background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation. You muse know this material before you start programming in (almost) any language!

Comment: The short form to demo the difference: `writeln(1+3, ' ', 1 or 3);`
Why this question is devalued remains a mystery to me.  Giving no points is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, in this situation, it should not make a difference. Binary bit fields will not cause any overflows if you use `+` as long as there's just one bit per value and you don't use any value more than once.

But to be safe, your best bet is to use logical operators when you want to perform logical or bitwise operations -- which is what you're doing here.

So using `or` would be the recommended practice.